# SASS, задать высоту изображению, исходя из его ширины

Tags: css, изображения, sass

Изображение должно занимать 100% ширины блока. Блок резиновый, до определённых моментов. Мне нужно, чтобы высота изображения была в 3,3 раза меньше, чем ширина. Как это задать в SASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Вариант с img {position: absolute;}

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/100/1" alt="">    
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/200/1" alt="">    
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/50/1" alt="">    
  </div>
</div>
```

[Или смотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/wut6umk5/)

## Вариант с инлайновым background-image

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/100/1');"></div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/200/1');"></div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/320/50/1');"></div>
</div>
```

[Или смотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/bLs1jst8/)

Comment: В теге img если задаёшь высоту в процентах, то проценты эти берутся не из изображения, а из высоты блока. То есть, вы только что задали изображению высоту, равную 30% высоты родительского блока. А если она у родителя не указана, то высота вообще для изображения будет автоматически выставлена. В общем, так ничего не работает

Comment: Необходим как раз общий случай, потому что у изображений может быть разная высота. И бэкграундом там тоже нельзя заменить.

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо за уточнения, исправил ответ, решается двумя вариантами.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%; 
}

.wrapper-inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    border: none;
}

.ratio-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

.xwrapper {
    padding-top: 30.30%; /* 100% ширины делим на 3.3 */
}
img{
  max-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-inner xwrapper">
        <div class="ratio-content">
            <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```